# Can you sacrifice Fleshbag Marauder to Ashnod's Altar, when it comes into play, if you have no other creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Can you sacrifice [Fleshbag Marauder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fleshbag%20Marauder) to [Ashnod's Altar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashnod%27s%20Altar), when it comes into play, if you have no other creatures? Would other players still be forced to sacrifice a creature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can sacrifice Fleshbag Marauder before its ability resolves. Your opponent still has to sacrifice a creature.**

Fleshbag Marauder's ability is a *triggered ability*. When Fleshbag Marauder enters the battlefield, the ability goes on the stack and players have the opportunity to react to it with instant-speed abilities (such as Ashnod's Altar) and spells, and it exists independently of the source that created it. When it comes to resolving the ability, it will ignore impossible instructions (when you have no creatures at that point) and carry out the rest (opponent has to sacrifice one of theirs, if they have any).

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]”

> 603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority. See rule 117, “Timing and Priority.” The ability becomes the topmost object on the stack. It has the text of the ability that created it, and no other characteristics. It remains on the stack until it’s countered, it resolves, a rule causes it to be removed from the stack, or an effect moves it elsewhere.

> 113.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won’t affect the ability. [..]

> 609.3. If an effect attempts to do something impossible, it does only as much as possible.
>
> Example: If a player is holding only one card, an effect that reads “Discard two cards” causes them to discard only that card. If an effect moves cards out of the library (as opposed to drawing), it moves as many as possible.

Comment: You could improve this by mentioning that "have no other creatures" is not directly relevant.  If you have other creatures, you could still sacrifice Fleshbag Marauder before its ability activates; the ability would still go off, and when it goes off *if* you have any creatures, you must sacrifice one.  And if you have none, you don't have to sacrifice any.  (This highlights a possible misconception the OP may have)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can sacrifice Fleshbag Marauder to the Altar before you have to sacrifice it to the ability.**

[Fleshbag Marauder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fleshbag%20Marauder)'s ability is what's called a triggered ability. It triggers when the permanent enters the battlefield in this case, is soon after put on the stack, and before it resolves, players have the opportunity to respond to it by casting spells and activating abilities. Creatures will only have to be sacrificed once the ability resolves.

[Ashnod's Altar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashnod%27s%20Altar) has an activated ability that you can activate in response to the Marauder's triggered ability. Because the Marauder is still in play, you can use it to pay the costs of the Altar's ability, which is to sacrifice a creature. Likewise, this ability will be put on the stack, and grant you two colorless mana when it resolves.

After the Altar's ability resolves, and as before assuming that nothing else happens, the Marauder's ability resolves and will cause each player to sacrifice a creature. If the Marauder was indeed your only creature, you don't have do do anything else at this point, as you will no longer have any creature to sacrifice. Other players will sill have to sacrifice creatures, since the ability doesn't make it a condition that *you* sacrifice a creature.

If you do have other creatures at this point, you would need to sacrifice another creature, as you have to choose which creature to sacrifice on resolution of the ability. However, to answer your question directly, you can always sacrifice the Marauder to the Altar for mana before you have to sacrifice it, whether you have other creatures or not.